# PhantomJs Injecting jQuery in different pages

Tags: phantomjs

I have a PhantomJs script in which I create a new wepage, inject jQuery into it and scrape a list of URL from it. After that I call a function passing the list of URL and create a new webpage for each one and try to recover certain information from it

```js
var pageGlobal = require('webpage');

function createPage(){
    var page = pageGlobal.create();
    page.onAlert = function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    };

    return page;
}

var page=createPage();
page.open('http://www.example.com/', function(status){

    if ( status === "success" ) {
        page.injectJs('jquery-1.6.1.min.js');

        var urlList=page.evaluate(
             function(){
                var urlList=[];
                window.console.log = function(msg) { alert(msg) }; 
                $("td.row1>a").each(function(index, link) {
                    var link=$(link).attr('href');
                    urlList.push(link);
                });
                return urlList;
            });

       processUrlList(urlList);
    }
});

function processUrlList(urlList){
    for(i=0;i<urlList.length;i++){
        var currentPage=createPage();
        currentPage.open("http://www.example.com"+urlList[i], function(status){

        if ( status === "success" ) {
            if(currentPage.injectJs('jquery-1.6.1.min.js')===false){
                console.log("Error en la inyeccion");
            }

            currentPage.evaluate(function() {
                window.console.log = function(msg) { alert(msg) }; 
                console.log("Evaluating");
                $("showAdText").each(function(index, link) {
                    //Capture information about the entity in this URL
                })
            });
        }
});
    }
}
```

The problem is in the processUrlList function the injection of jQuery always fail returning false. Would it be a problem to create two or more page objects instead of reusing only one? What could be happening here?

Comment: 1. What happens when you completely remove the injection of jQuery in `processUrlList`? I think you don't need it, since it was already injected into the first page. 2. I think it is better to rewrite `processUrlList` to do asynchronous recursion instead of a for loop. The for loop might introduce some race conditions. 3. Why do you register to `onAlert` and change the `console.log` implementation in the page to `alert` only to end up in the console. You should simply register to `onConsoleMessage`.

Comment: Thank you for your advices (I wasn't aware of the onConsoleMessage). However the removal of the injection in processUrlList didn't work, may be because I am creating a new page object in each iteration (problem that I corrected too)

Comment: Since there are no answer, you can replace your question code with the improved version.